# Am i correct in the way I am deciding whether or not subsets of $\Bbb R^3$ are surfaces or not?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

I just want to make sure that there isn't any gaps in my reasoning ( or flat out mistakes!) before I try to learn anymore about classifying subsets of $\Bbb R^3$ as surfaces, so to that end .....

Consider the subsets of $\Bbb R^3$

i) $S^2=\{(x,y,z)\in \Bbb R ^3 | x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$

ii) $A=\{(x,y,z)\in \Bbb R^3|x^2+z^2=y^2\}$

In deciding whether or not these are surfaces I know we can use a corollary of the implicit function from calculus.

Theorem :suppose $f:\Bbb R^3 \rightarrow \Bbb R$ is smooth and c is a regular value of $f$, with $f^{-1}(c)\neq(0,0,0)$, then $f^{-1}(c)$ is a surface in $\Bbb R^3$.

Here is my attempt at using the corollary:

.

.

i)$S^2=\{(x,y,z) \in \Bbb R^3 |x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$

let $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$, clearly f is smooth and maps $\Bbb R^3 \rightarrow \Bbb R$.

$Df=(\partial f/\partial x, \partial f/\partial y,\partial f/\partial z)=(2x,2y,2z)$

so every point except the origin is a regular point.

$\Rightarrow f(0,0,0)=0$ is the only critical value of f and so $f^{-1}(1)=x^2+y^2+z^2$
describes a surface as 1 is a regular value , and so $S^2$ is a surface.

.

.

ii)let $f(x)=x^2+z^2-y^2$
again this is smooth with the proper mapping needed.

$Df=(2x,2z,-2y)$

so again the only critical point is the origin

$\Rightarrow f(0,0,0)=0$ is the only critical value

so $f^{-1}(0)=x^2+z^2-y^2$ does not describe a surface so A is not a surface.

Comment: The implicit function theorem is *not* an if and only if theorem. So your proof of i) is correct because it uses the logical direction that *is* stated in the implicit function theorem, but your proof of ii) is invalid because it uses the other logical direction which *is not* stated.

Comment: For example, if we take $f(x,y,z)=z^2$ then $f(x,y,z)=0$ does define a surface, namely the $x$,$y$ plane given by the equation $z=0$, and this is so *even though* $0$ is a critical value of $f$ and every point $(x,y,0)$ on the surface is a critical point.

Comment: See, among other answers, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1357697/is-m-x-y-in-bbbr2-x2-y5-a-differentiable-submanifold/1357857#1357857) important characterization of smooth surfaces or submanifolds as specific graphs.

Comment: @LeeMosher for number ii then would the following argument work : if we take the coordinate patch to be the function $\bar x (x,z)\rightarrow (x,y,z)$ but then note that $y=-\sqrt{x^2+z^2}$ meaning that the partial derivatives of y are $\tfrac{-z}{\sqrt{x^2+z^2}}$ and $\tfrac{-x}{\sqrt{x^2+z^2}}$ which are not differentiable at (0,0) and so we can't have a surface if the domain of the co-ordinate patch contains this point ? I feel like my argument may be a little shaky but is that the right idea to move forward with ?

Comment: That's a profitable idea, I think, but the trouble is that you do not have the freedom to work with just a single convenient coordinate chart. If you wish to do a proof by examination of coordinate charts then you have to prove that *no possible* coordinate chart could work.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1754171/why-is-this-proof-that-a-circular-cone-is-not-a-surface-not-rigorous/2975326 I was kind of building of the proposition that Leo lorena posted , I'm having a lot of trouble getting this particular topic would you mind explaining how come my answer is different than the proposition ?

Answer (score 0):

An intuitive argument as to why $S^{2}$ is a surface can be made as such: it can be covered with 6 co-ordinate patches (up,down,right,left,front & back), and thus each point on it lies in the image of one of the 6 coordinate patches.

As for the second part, your main error is using the implicit function theorem as an If and only if statement.

Comment: I would like to add that it was User Lee Mosher who had initially stated the second part of my answer, so credit to him.